# plotly tickformat does not apply german locale number format

Tags: numbers, format, plotly

I am trying to display data using plotly.js with german number formatting for example: "1.234,0"

layout = {
    yaxis: {
        tickformat: ',.'
    }
}

But it does not work for me.

I have found working example:

https://plot.ly/2503/~chris/

How do I achieve this ?

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry - correction:  tickformat: '.,'

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I was trying to achieve it by using hoverformat  but with no success.

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose, you should use the separators property in layout, like this:

```
layout = { separators = ',.' }
```

where the first character is the decimal separator, and the second is the thousand separator. For more information, please refer to https://plot.ly/javascript-graphing-library/reference/#layout-separators.

For number formatting, you should use the hoverformat in layout.xaxis or layout.yaxis. So, to solve your issue, you may use the following:

```
layout = { 
           separators = ',.',
           yaxis: { hoverformat = '.1f' }
         }
```

Hope this helps.